# Spring Boot Authorization Basic Header Never Changes

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am attempting to setup a very basic spring boot authenticated application.  I am setting the Authorization header in the client and sending it to the backend.  I can verify that the client is sending the correct header.

The backend receives the header correctly on the first attempt to login.  However if the login credentials are incorrect subsequent requests retain whatever the header for the intial request was (caching it or something).

I am using Redis to Cache the session.  My config is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            ;
    }
}
```

AuthenticationEntryPoint

```
public class AuthenticationEntryPointBean {
@Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }
}
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

** Edit **
Adding cache settings

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(); // <2>
    }
}
```

Also I am trying to invalidate cache but that doesn't seem to work

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value="/auth/login", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody String login(@RequestHeader(name = "authorization") String authorization, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            authorization = authorization.substring("Basic ".length());
            String decoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(authorization),"UTF-8");

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            LoginRequest login = gson.fromJson(decoded,LoginRequest.class);

            UserAuthenticationEntity entity = service.getSecurityContext(login).orElseThrow(() ->
                new BadCredentialsException("Authentication Failed.")
            );

            session.setMaxInactiveInterval((int)TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(expiresInMinutes));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new EntityContext(entity,expiresInMinutes));

            String response = gson.toJson(BasicResponse.SUCCESS);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            session.invalidate();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Authentication Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to include your cache configuration in the question. An off-the-cuff guess is that the cache is incorrectly configured so that it doesn't know to invalidate the cache contents on failed login, so it just returns the cached session info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following to my web security config seemed to do the trick.

```
.requestCache()
.requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
```

I am not sure what side effects are of doing this.  I picked it up off of a blog https://drissamri.be/blog/2015/05/21/spring-security-and-spring-session/

If there is any more insight into if this is good practice or bad practice I would appreciate any comments.

My final web security config looks like the following:

```
 http
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
        .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionFixation()
            .newSession()
            ;
```

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much what you needed. Without that `.requestCache(new NullRequestCache())`, the *request* is being cached, which is why a second login attempt was showing up with the same parameters.